# Can a server justify a permanent establishment in a tax manner?

Tags: international, tax-law

Let's assume I am located in Germany, but I am operating servers in some other country, for example Ireland. My fictional business is running these servers to rent them out to others (like hosting others websites, databases and similar stuff). So, basically I would provide my customers a service - which, however, mostly consists of giving them access to my servers and to keep the servers up and running (such as fixing broken hardware, installing updates, ...).

By "my servers", I mean hardware equipment which I own and is permanently assembled in some space in a larger datacenter (in another country, not the country where I am residing). Thus, I am renting a shelf (a so called [server rack](https://5.imimg.com/data5/OS/WH/LT/SELLER-89433814/19-inch-server-rack-500x500.jpg)) in the datacenter to place the servers there and also pay for internet and power to run them.

Thought, I had to be physically present to install them there, most of the maintenance work can be done remotely. (Well, actually, I could also pay somebody to install them there and wouldn't need to present. In case it would change something from a tax perspective: assume I did it myself.)

Now my actual question: **In which country would the income of this arrangement be taxable?**

The *OECD Model Tax-Convention* (which a lot of international tax treaties are based on, including Germany-Ireland) seems to relate that to the definition of "permanent establishments" and that each profit must be assigned to one establishment and then be taxed in that country. The above sample would thus consist of two permanent establishments from which this business is run: the servers in the data center in Ireland and my home-office in Germany from which I'm operating most of the time.

But, how would one now attribute the profits to each establishment? In my opinion, the servers clearly are the main income-generating asset and thus most (or all) income should be attributed to Ireland. On the other hand, one could also argue, that without my administrative work these server would not be able to generate income.

---

*(The above sample is fictional, especially the choice of countries. The choice, such as Germany-Ireland, has just been made to be more specific in case it would matter for the answer. An answer doesn't need to be specific to these two countries. I'm more interested in the general answer to this question.)*

---

Some additional, maybe helpful notes: The closest publication on this matter I found so far is an OECD working paper on the matter of taxing e-commerce income from 2001: "[ATTRIBUTION OF PROFIT TO A PERMANENT ESTABLISHMENT INVOLVED IN ELECTRONIC COMMERCE TRANSACTIONS](http://www.oecd.org/tax/treaties/1923312.pdf)".

However, this publication doesn't answer the question when the servers are the core of the business (such as in the above sample). Instead, they look at it from a perspective where the servers are just part of a larger business, such as when operating an online shop on those servers. Thought, they come to the conclusion that some of the profits are attributable to servers too, while most of the profit would be attributed to the actual selling and distribution of the products (probably determined by the location of the warehouse).

Comment: Another note: I just found, that for some countries this might be easier to answer. The UK, for example, did issue an explicit statement, that they do not consider a server a permanent establishment (against OECD views, as they also stated): https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/international-manual/intm264700